# Extract a single String from an array of items

Tags: yahoo-pipes

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7447931/in-yahoo-pipes-how-can-i-return-a-single-value-from-a-loop-thats-built-with-va) was asked a few years ago, but the accepted answer is vague at best and confusing at worst.

I'm attempting to pass a number that I've retrieved via Regex from a fetched page as the source of a filter.

Here's the link to my pipe: http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=4c087880efe5ef2ea62261ff9e7eee1b

I need to get the emitted value from the loop (which is currently `555`) and pass that to the string builder so that it prepends a `#`; I will then pass that built string as the source for my greater than filter on the `item.title` of the fetched RSS feed.

Since the loop module outputs an array, I currently can't find a way to connect it to the string builder module.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://ambrusmartin.wordpress.com/2012/09/04/yahoo-pipes-merging-multiple-feeds-from-a-csv-file/

Comment: After reading over the blog post and looking at the example Pipe's source code, I'm afraid it's not what I'm looking for. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score -2):

Within `for` loop we can either get one String from list of String or we can use `split("")` method to divide String into words